# I want to merge one project data into another project in jenkins. How can I achieve this?

Tags: gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, karate

I have two project namely say X and Y
Where x contains all code and configuration
And Y contains testData and Feature files which is manage by some other team.
I had created a job in jenkins to run my X project initially which is working without any issue. Now I want at run time I poll the Y project and check if they had any new commits then first I merge it else leave it.
Currently I am able to check the last commit but still not able to merge project
My both X and Y are Karate API project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to design differently. Maybe the right solution is X should create a JAR file. And then in Y you depend on that JAR file. Now it has become a standard CI / Jenkins situation.

My advice is don't try to re-invent polling and merging and whatnot - those are all solved problems.

Comment: @pthomas That thing I already achieved, I kept my java code in separate jar file and uploaded on nexus. 
Problem is that we have various type of input data and that be filled by different people, I only want that the team who supposed to enter test data should only have limited access to update test data , On analysing different solution we come to that if we kept test data as seperate project and through jenkins pipeline we merge them at build time.

Comment: @shivam I strongly advise not to go for this kind of over-engineering, it never ends well. I have no other advice for you, all the best.

Comment: @pthomas Thanks for feedback, I will try to look another approach

Comment: @prthomas I achieve this using git submodule concept and it not required anything to done on CI.  ```git submodule add <repository URL```

Answer (score 0):

I achieve this using git submodule concept and it not required anything to done on CI. 
`git submodule add <repository URL`